# iMac12,1: Fuzzy display

Tags: xubuntu, display, 23.10

I'm currently running Xubuntu 23.10 on my mid-2011 iMac (iMac12,1). I've noticed a minor issue, The built-in display has a slight fuzzing/static effect especially with dark colors. Am I missing a driver or what?

Edit: I have the AMD Radeon HD 6730M installed.

Comment: For older iMacs, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1363708/1222991) may be of assistance 